# Can Stack Overflow release Google Analytics data for us to view stats and stuff?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Wouldn't it be great if we could have a "Stack Overflow Analytics Explorer", similar to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Would something like this be possible?, So we (the public) could analyze the data for research and stuff?

Even an exported format CSV or something.

I'd love to have a look at some of this data if it was available (or even a small subset), I'm sure others would to.

Things like:

- Technology (Browser, OS & Network stats)
- Mobile information
- Demographics (if available)
- Bounce rates for some of the most popular keywords
- Maybe other things like organic keywords and stuff (if you can share it legally)

Would this even be allowed in Google's terms and conditions?

Maybe a blog post once a year or something summarizing all the above?

Comment: UA spoofing aside, browser, OS, and resolutions would be very fun stats to see. Probably won't get a better sample for our peers than StackOverflow statistics.

Comment: well Google analytics does have an API.

Comment: I have Tracking Protection enabled in IE; will the data include me?

Comment: I'd love to get a sense of the referrers too.  I'm sure that most would be from Google, Twitter & various tech blogs... but a breakdown would be neat. e.g. what percentage comes in from "the hyphen site"? ;-)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi no, Tracking Protection blocks Google Analytics.

Comment: @scunliffe what's "the hyphen site"?

Comment: @bamboon Experts Exchange

Comment: It meight be interesting too to the see correlation between browser/os and the tags of a question.

Comment: I would think hardly any come in through EE, as some peple I know of have made comments about the conent on the two sites looking very similar when SO was written first without attribution. As to GA in general, I wonder how many people do not have privacy mode on in their browser here? Would the analytics really be that useful?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't Google Analytics, but I remembered looking a few months ago at Quantcast for some analytics, and they have openly available data on Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network.

https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?qcLocale=en_US

You can see all sorts of fun demographics there. I don't know how accurate it is, but I assume it's no worse than Google Analytics. But it does seem a little too good to be true. Not that I wouldn't expect this information to be available, but it surprises me that it's publicly available and *free.*

They have data on gender, age, whether people have children, income, education, ethnicity, political affiliation, and whether people are politically active. They also show interests of users like GA can, and some geographic information.

I'm not sure whether they have referrers (although that certainly wouldn't surprise me), but this is at least some information.

Then zooming out a bit, you can also view data from the entire Stack Exchange network (thanks to –  @SztupY for pointing out that they have subdomains of stackexchange.com that encompass most if not all SE sites).

They also have analytics on a number of other websites, for those of us who just find that kind of thing fun.

You also can't, of course, run the sorts of queries you might be able to if this were something proprietary, and it would be cool to have it exposed through the UI like the Data Explorer does. But at least this way you can get the data, even if it isn't quite as nice as it could be.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one who hardly visits the site outside the working week

Comment: You can check the subdomains under stackexchange.com separately: https://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com?country=US#!subdomain

Comment: @SztupY ah, good point. That hadn't occurred to me. I'll edit my answer and take that out. Thanks.

Comment: how do they measure ethnicity or political affiliation?

Comment: @UmNyobe I was wondering that. I know services like Google or Facebook can determine things like that through searching habits, and the political organizations have pretty solid markers to decide which party someone would vote for (there are lots of documentaries that go into that kind of thing, of course), so I'm sure the data is available to some people out there. But as I said in the post, it surprises me that it's public and free. The site seems respectable enough, though, so I assume they have some backing. But I'd still take it with a grain of salt for sure.

Answer (score 7):

I guess Stack Exchange team is using Google Analytics data for their own private work.

From [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85926/233367),

> Moderators have access to a panel which shows them analytics now.

---

> Maybe a blog post once a year or something summarising all the above?

**Yes.**  Each year Stack Overflow conducts [Annual User Survey](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-annual-survey/) which encompasses all the data that you have requested.

> We need a Stack Overflow Annual User Survey.

Why? – To measure our user’s demographics
Why? – Potential advertisers judge our site by demographics to see if we fit in with their goals
Why? – You’ll see more relevant ads increasing the value of our advertising
Why? – With more valued advertisers, we can spend more time developing awesome new features
Why? – New features create a better user experience, supporting Stack Overflow’s mission to make the internet a better place than we found it.

Here is the collection of the Stack Overflow User Survey Results (2010 - 2013)

[2013 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/)
[2012 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/)
[2011 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/survey-results/)
[2010 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/)

To download these survey results, check this [Shared Google drive](https://drive.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/#folders/0BwIexitMAu8ceG95UUkyUGlRM0U)

Comment: The Analytics data is much likely to be better and more complete than the survey though.