# Is the raw data from the 2015 Developer Survey available?

Tags: feature-request, survey, survey-2015

Will Stack Exchange publish anonymous raw data behind the annual [Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285178/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2015-now-closed)?

I found [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270452/can-stack-overflow-release-google-analytics-data-for-us-to-view-stats-and-stuff/270523#270523) which links to datasets for 2010-2013, but it'd be great to have more recent data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies, just seeing this. The full line-by-line survey results were released several months ago. You can find them at the link at the bottom of the official survey results:

https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#community-answer

The raw data has been stripped of all personally identifiable information.