# Raw Data for 2016 Survey

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, survey-2016

Can the raw data used to formulate the 2016 Developer Survey results be published?  This [was done for the 2015 survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290005/is-the-raw-data-from-the-2015-developer-survey-available).

Comment: It will be, in a few weeks. As was the data for the 2015 survey :)

Comment: By stating *a few weeks*, Oded means, 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: @Oded Not to be impatient, but... any update? I'm excited to do some number crunching — we're trying to make Fedora Workstation more appealing to developers, and this is an exciting way we can make data-driven decisions rather than going on anecdotes or guessing.

Comment: @mattdm - I know the team is working on finishing up cleaning up the data (from any privately identifying info) - just got the email a couple of days ago. So - soon?

Comment: @Oded Awesome! Thanks so much (both for the update and for providing such extensive data).

Comment: @Oded any update on when we will see the raw data?

Comment: @onebree - I asked around and was told we will try to get it out in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 18):

From [the announcement of the 2016 results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/03/stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/?cb=1):

> Thank you to everyone who participated in our survey and shared information about yourself. **We’ll be releasing the full data set in just a few weeks.** Do you have ideas for what we should ask about next year? Tell us in the comments.

(emphasis mine)

So to answer your question: yes, the raw data **can** be published. It also **will** be published... in a few weeks. :p

#### Edit: 18 weeks is a little longer than 6-8 weeks, but it's [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/you-can-now-download-stack-overflows-2016-developer-survey-data/?cb=1)!

[Here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/you-can-now-download-stack-overflows-2016-developer-survey-data/?cb=1) is a blog post announcing the release of the raw data.

You can access the data for this year and previous years from the [research portal](https://stackoverflow.com/research).

[Here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0DL28AqnGsrV0VldnVIT1hyb0E) is a direct link to the raw data.

Comment: I would guess in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @rekire [i-understand-that-reference.jpg]

Comment: Ok, it should be available by now, right? If so, where can I find the link to it?

Comment: @Kira It's here! I've edited my answer to include the relevant links.