# Any info on where people signed up to Stack Overflow Careers end up working

Tags: discussion

Do we have any statistics on the percentages of people signed up to Stack Overflow Careers (*and* highly active on the main site -- wouldn't be fair otherwise) who end up going into paid employment within the industry, and/or the sort of subsections of the industry these illustrious pillars of the community usually find themselves in? Are there hundreds upon hundreds of Aerospace Computer Scientists, Robotics Wunderkind, Fight Jet Systems Engineers and John Skeet Missionaries, or are people struggling to get minimum wage positions writing HTML for toilet cleaning firms and flushing out caches for known tyrant paper merchants based in Slough?

Just wondering what those "good-looking rebels who play by their own rules"*, with their heinous misdeeds and/or impish revelry are missing out on in terms of employment opportunities their betters are earning by their rigorous and steadfast work to help grow the community and provide the sort of reference source material [Strunk and White](https://xkcd.com/923/) would be envious of.

*as Bart Simpson would say

Comment: Neither employers nor job seekers are likely to reliably report this kind of information, so probably no. The best you'll get is the data from the Stack Overflow survey (where folks can state whether they got their current job through Careers IIRC, and state their income level if they want to.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Where can I find that? Is it something you guys store on your servers?

Comment: I'm not affiliated with SO. Re data, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319228/raw-data-for-2016-survey might be worth another poke, it's been a while since March

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'll give it a good poke for you. Seems like an interesting bundle of data...