# Raw Data for 2017 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey

In similar vein to the [2016 survey results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319228/raw-data-for-2016-survey)… ;)

Curious if there's a rough timeline for when the raw data for the 2017 survey might be out? It would be very helpful for me.

Also, just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to run this survey and sharing the results. It's a hugely useful window into the industry.